# How to return more then one result with zpop in Redis

Tags: redis

Zpop command in Redis returns a single result

Is there a way for zpop more then one result in a single execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Redis are you using? According to official documentation, Redis has `ZPOPMIN` and `ZPOPMAX` and no `ZPOP` command.

The [`ZPOPMIN`](https://redis.io/commands/zpopmin) and [`ZPOPMAX`](https://redis.io/commands/zpopmax) commands both accept as a second optional argument the amount of members to pop.